# WPF TreeView: Callback for node/item child selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Consider the following `TreeView` in WPF:

```
Parent node 0
|-> Child node 0
    |-> Grandchild node 0
    |-> Grandchild node 1
    |-> ...
```

It can be defined with XAML like so:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Parent node 0">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child node 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStringEnumerable}" Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Where `MyStringEnumerable` is a `IEnumerable<string>`. The `TreeViewItem_Selected` callback is called when the Child or Grandchild nodes/items are selected. The problem is that I only want this callback to be called when Grandchild nodes/items are selected. How can I implement this with minimal code changes? Ideally, I would like to have a `ChildSelected` event instead of `Selected`, but this is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [hierachical data template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=net-5.0), and  - given Grandchild and Child also refer to different (viewmodel) types - only attach the eventhandler to the template for Grandchild.
Else if it's the same type, use a template selector.
Also I would recommend to bind a viewmodel property to the treeviewitem's [IsSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isselected?view=net-5.0) property, rather then handling the event in code behind.